# which is a right way to write list Item

Tags: grammar, list-order

Below are the example to write a List, which is a right way to write list Item

Example 1 :
4).Upload with File Restrictions

Example 2 :
4) Upload with File Restrictions

Comment: If you have a style guide to follow, follow that style guide. If you're not bound by a style guide, you can do whatever you want, as long as you do it consistently to all items. That said, there is no reason to use two punctuation marks where one will do. And there is *absolutely* no reason to not put a whitespace after the period.